# Custom Queries - Child Categories not showing up

Tags: customization, filters, query-posts

**What I'm Doing**

I have a cities category and normal categories. Right now I have them filtering by category, then when the user clicks a city it will filter by category AND city

`query_posts(array( 'category__and' => array($city, $category))`

**The Problem**

That works - no problem. The problem comes when I add sub-categories to my main `$categories` and the admin does not check the parent.

**Example**

I have a main category: `Food` and 2 sub-categories `Fries` & `Burgers`. I also have a city category called `New York`. The admin adds a post and checks `Fries` and `New York` so by default wordpress will pull up this post. When the user tries to filter it by city (`New York`) it says there's no posts because the parent was never checked.

---

How do I Bring that sub-category post to the top when the user filters the parent category by city?

I apologize if it is confusing so ask questions if needed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`category__and` is exclusive, so it will not work for your application, if you use `tax_query` and setup your query as follows, it should work:

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $city,
            //'include_children' is true by default
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category', //may need to be categories, I don't recall, tweak it till it works.
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $category,
            //'include_children', again, is true by default
        )
    )
);
$posts = query_posts( $args );
```

If that doesn't sit well with `query_posts()` (I don't see any reason it wouldn't), [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) won't complain, so just use that. Also, that link to `WP_Query` has all the docs you'll need to modify that query, so thumb through there, you'll probably at least want `'post_status' => 'publish'`...maybe some more.

Comment: OK, so this looks like what I need but now I'm just trying to wrap my head around the terms. From my understanding `taxonomy` would be the parent category, `field` is the slug ID and `terms` would be the sub-category? I figured $city / $category would be in `taxonomy` but maybe I don't fully understand the keywords here.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? I don't understand your question. `taonomy` is things like tags, categories, or the slug of a taxonomy you registered with `register_taxonomy()`. `field` is either `slug` or `id`, depending on whether you want to use the category ID or the slug as the identifier in `terms`. `terms` is your slugs or ids (string or array). I STRONGLY encourage you to read the documentation and just play around with the function, it's not writing to the database, so you can't fubar anything.

Comment: I think I see how taxonomy works (or at least a bit) but it seems that `register_taxonomy()` is just another step for the admin to take which I am trying to avoid. I mean if I wanted I could just tell the admin to simply check the parent category whenever they make posts but I'm trying to get around that somehow.

Comment: Register taxonomy is only for custom taxonomies, you can use the built in taxonomies (tags and categories) as well.

Comment: Ohhh I see. Thanks :D ! Taxonomy was pretty confusing until I played around with all the different terms I could put in there and how it worked. I edited your answer to the code that fit my need (that worked for me). Thanks again!